# Modifying geometry from FusionTablesLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Google Maps JS API and Fusion Tables API.

I've got a Fusion Table containing geometry data (from shapefile, using shpescape.com). I'm trying to overlay this data on a map, using FusionTablesLayer. Now, I want to render every polygon in a different colour, based on a numeric value assigned to it, just like normal Fusion Tables functionality does (Visualise on map).

The problem is that I can't store numeric values in Fusion Table, because I need to change them very often. Geometry in Fusion Table has an ID assigned to it, also, in Javascript, I have an array that contains mapping: GeometryID => Value (let's assume the value is in range from 1 to 100).

How to change colours of the geometry (ie. 5 colours, value in range 0-20 -> first colour, 20-40 -> second coloud etc.) according to the data that's stored in Javascript array?

Answer (score 0):

Data from one FusionTablesLayer can be [styled](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) in the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, since I want to be able to assign different styles to geometry based on external data, not data from the Fusion Table. Styling uses values that are stored in the same table as geometry and I want to be able to style them using ie. data in JavaScript.

Comment: If information on how to define and change the styles from Javascript doesn't answer your question, then you need to clarify your question, perhaps even give a link to your map and explain how you are trying to enhance it.